# How to plot dates read from a csv file on the x axis

Tags: csv, date, octave

I've been having a bit of a struggle plotting Temperature vs Dates in Octave.
I am reading the dates from a csv file, I am doing this:

```
TempData=csv2cell(filename.csv,1) %File with dates and temperatures

Date=TempData(:,2) %Second column has the dates in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

datev=datevec(Date:31) % which gives me an output by columns 

date2=datenum(datev)
```

Then I plot:

```
plot(date2,MeanT)
```

And I get this output:

[The image is what I want, but the x axis should state the dates in their YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBZ4l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `datetick` (i.e. type `help datetick` in an octave terminal).

E.g.

```
datetick( 'x', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
```

will convert your x-axis which consists of datenum values into string ticklabels in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format (e.g. '2021-08-20').

If you require a different format, have a look at `help datestr`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `datetick`

```
datetick('x','yyyy-mm-dd')
```